# Spring MVC OAUTH2 with JWT Token xml configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I have already implemented oauth2 using DefaultTokenServices. This will return uuid for the access token and refresh token. I need to return JWT tokens instead.

Most resources point to spring boot configuration, how can we do that in Spring mvc XML?

Currently this is the response when I call `/oauth/token?grant_type=password`

Response:

```
{
    "access_token": "43923b9b-2bf0-47db-a36a-87ae5b2734d9",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "7586ee7c-f7c7-4fa5-960d-4fa35ca2dbac",
    "expires_in": 99,
    "scope": " trust  write read"
}
```

spring-security.xml

```xml
<beans:bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />
  
  <beans:bean id="requestFactory"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- token based configurations-->
    <beans:bean id="tokenServices"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <beans:property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="100" />
        <beans:property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </beans:bean>
    
    <beans:bean id="userApprovalHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
        <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
        <beans:property name="requestFactory" ref="requestFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
 
    <oauth:authorization-server
            client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
            user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"  resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

    <!--client configuration-->
    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
        <oauth:client client-id="app"
                      authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials,password,refresh_token,implicit"
                      scope="read, write, trust"
                      secret="123456"/>
    </oauth:client-details-service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by adding the following lines to spring-security.xml

```xml
    <!-- token enhancer for jwt -->
    <beans:bean id="accessTokenConverter"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter">
        <beans:property name="signingKey" value="8tQ2OKIiHMRKZlBHvUW1WyUXk91bJfUMPeh61kAe7YPbdJ5ekRDIHQs8dOkpQc6" />
    </beans:bean>
    
    <beans:bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="accessTokenConverter" />
        <beans:property name="tokenEnhancer" ref="accessTokenConverter" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- token based configurations-->
    <beans:bean id="tokenServices"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <beans:property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="100" />
        <beans:property name="tokenEnhancer" ref="accessTokenConverter" />
        <beans:property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Response:

```json
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2ODI0NTkzMjAsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6InFyLXJlZmxleCIsImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjpbIlJPTEVfUVJfUFJPVklERVJfQVBJIl0sImp0aSI6IjhkZGM5YzY0LTk5NmUtNDk3MC04YmZjLWZjYTYxMDkzYjI1OSIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImFwcCIsInNjb3BlIjpbIiB0cnVzdCIsIiB3cml0ZSIsInJlYWQiXX0.0uHEgrI7a4KqAUQ-g1eiLb-XEfuakzyhNGAGmo7tIT4",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2ODUwNTEyMjAsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6InFyLXJlZmxleCIsImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjpbIlJPTEVfUVJfUFJPVklERVJfQVBJIl0sImp0aSI6IjQ0NzM3ZDFlLWJhNjItNDY4YS05Zjc4LTJhNWI2MzUwNmNjMiIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImFwcCIsInNjb3BlIjpbIiB0cnVzdCIsIiB3cml0ZSIsInJlYWQiXX0.bj1erKMh3RCQZhLSxXSzmJHE11-Y062G8w2qvMmblV8",
    "expires_in": 99,
    "scope": " trust  write read",
    "jti": "8ddc9c64-996e-4970-8bfc-fca61093b259"
}
```